# anti derivative from $u$ to $u' $

Tags: calculus

so we have U as $ U = (y'' + y)/(y' + y) $
and we need to get $ U' $

would quotient rule apply when we do reverse derivation (anti derivative)

or it will be simply

$$ U' = (y''' + y')/(y'' + y')  $$

Comment: Of course you have to use quotient rule - you cannot just place a derivative onto every part individually.

Comment: so quotient rule in reverse. Thanks I will check my books for examples.:)

Comment: so can I start by writing  $ U = (y'' + y) (y'+y)^{-1}  $

Comment: Also this is a derivative not an antiderivative